# How to serialize GraphClient results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

After receiving data back from the `GraphClient`, such as a `CallRecord`, how do we correctly serialize the data so as to not lose any properties. I tried simply using System.Text.Json but I think because a lot of the types inside are parent classes not the runtime concrete classes, a lot of fields get lost, for example, CallRecord.Sessions.Caller.Identity.
I see that `CallRecord` has a .Serialize method, but I can't find any documentation on how to use this. In fact I can't find much documentation on anything for the .Net SDK.

This is a two parter, first how do I serialize without losing fields, and where is all the documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would just be to use the native Graph Response which is JSON, the Graph SDK classes don't always capture all the properties eg things end up in the AdditionalData as the backend changes etc. If your using the new Kiota based SDK then you just use the NativeResponseHandler eg something like

```
        var nativeResponseHandler = new NativeResponseHandler();
        var callRecord = graphServiceClient.Communications.CallRecords[callId].GetAsync(requestConfiguration => requestConfiguration.Options.Add(new ResponseHandlerOption() { ResponseHandler = nativeResponseHandler })).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var responseMessage = nativeResponseHandler.Value as HttpResponseMessage;
        var jsonResponse = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

in the v4 SDK you can do your own DelegatingHandler to do the same sort of thing.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that we need to add some of our own data into the additional data fields around the place before serializing. So our flow is: Get data -> Aggregate -> Serialize, which means we really need to be able to serialize the actual CallRecord object. We are just using the v4 SDK, not Kiota